# PLS-00362 When Creating Strongly-Typed Ref Cursor Of ref_cursor_type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been trying out each variation in the PL/SQL syntax diagram for declaring PL/SQL TYPE's for strongly-typed REF CURSOR's ([Oracle 21 Documentation - Cursor Variable Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/cursor-variable-declaration.html#GUID-CE884B31-07F0-46AA-8067-EBAF73821F3D__CJAJDAAI)) using Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0.

I've created working example PL/SQL code for all the syntax variations, except for last variation in the syntax diagram: "TYPE type IS REF CURSOR RETURN **ref_cursor_type**". According to the documentation mentioned above, a "ref_cursor_type" is:

> Name of a user-defined type that was defined with the data type specifier REF CURSOR.

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE myPkg AS
  TYPE t_UDTRefCursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN sys.all_arguments%ROWTYPE;
  
  TYPE t_MyCursorType IS REF CURSOR RETURN t_UDTRefCursor;
END;
```

But I get this error:

> Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
> Error(4,26): PLS-00362: invalid cursor return type; 'T_UDTREFCURSOR' must be a record type

[Oracle's documentation on PLS-00362](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/errmg/PLS-00001.html#GUID-C2E) says:

> PLS-00362: invalid cursor return type; 'string' must be a record type
>
> Cause: In a cursor specification or REF CURSOR type definition, a non- record type such as NUMBER or TABLE was specified as the return type. This is not allowed. Only the following return types are allowed: <record_type_name> <record_name>%TYPE <table_name>%ROWTYPE <cursor_name>%ROWTYPE <cursor_variable_name>%ROWTYTPE
>
> Action: Revise the cursor specification or REF CURSOR type definition so that it specifies one of the above return types.

This PLS error documentation lists **five** syntax options for RETURN, but the TYPE syntax diagram shows a **sixth** option of "ref_cursor_type".

How to I use this "TYPE type IS REF CURSOR RETURN ref_cursor_type" option mentioned in the documentation's syntax diagram?

Comment: Don't think this is possible, possible doc bug. If you want to share a record declaration between strong ref cursors you could declare a subtype of record type, record%type, table%rowtype or cursor%rowtype and share the subtype between ref cursor declarations.